# Do Macs in a corporate setting behave more erratically?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash, performance

I've used a MacBook Pro in my last two jobs (one was circa 2012, and my current one is 2015), and at home I have an iMac (circa 2009) and MacBook Air (circa 2013).  At home my Macs perform wonderfully - they hardly ever freeze or crash.  I use the iMac for multimedia applications such as Photoshop, Illustrator, etc., and the Air is more for general purpose internet/office apps (although Lightroom is used on it as well).

The work laptops tend to experience login times of up to 15-20 seconds when connected to the corporate network (and this tends to get worse over time), and sometimes I'll open up the laptop and find it's unresponsive.  My current laptop has 16 GB RAM, and the most memory-intensive application I use is Excel, and even then I'm not manipulating huge files.

Does anyone else have a similar experience with Macs at work?

Answer (score 2):

No - Macs in enterprise are generally less erratic, more agile, less expensive, more productive and let people get work done with less unpleasantness like cryptic error messages, slow deployments, hard to diagnose issues, and things that require a large, IT support orgainzation.

In 2015 - IBM was 6 months in to a user choice program allowing their employees to choose a Mac or a PC and they had realized faster deployment, less support and cost savings of somewhere south of $300 per device.

- https://www.jamf.com/blog/mac-ibm-zero-to-30000-in-6-months/

In 2016 - IBM is now betwwo 90k and 100k Macs deployed and is realizing savings of $250 to $500 per device type in cost to buy, support, provision Mac hardware versus PC hardware.

- https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/events/jnuc/2016/246/keynote-a-user-first-mentality?view=info
- https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/events/jnuc/2016/220/mac-ibm-under-the-hood?view=info

The videos from above should be posted within a month. Also keep in mind that this is a customer / partnership success story, but the hard numbers and experiences of people I spoke with make me feel these numbers are both fair and real as well as transferrable to many other enterprise organizations immediately with low risk if the company decides to support their employees and let them choose their platform to get work done.

If you are getting slow performance, it's likely due to something that can be fixed without a lot of delay if someone looks into the root cause and decides to support your location.

If you have stability issues - consider getting a good backup and wiping. Just add back the apps you need. My feelings are that the only changes that organizations make tend to increase stability of the Mac OS except for one.

- antivirus software other than Apple's GateKeeper and Xprotect are huge sources of delay, slowness, resource usage and breakage. Kernel extensions generally are buggy, slow to be ready for new releases, etc...
- Setting up restrictions like disabling iCloud sync generally make a Mac run better, not worse.
- Setting up a server to delay or restrict updates and patches generally makes a Mac more stable.
- Having IT to help you with backups and procedures to automate things like an erase instal and/or script setting things up like printers and such generally reduce the time you need to manage settings and don't cause any issues with stability.

Comment: Also - don't focus too much on the price to support unless you get some feedback from your support organization. If they can't afford to support you, then you can wonder where they are spending their budget.

Comment: What I mean by my question is are they more erratic compared a Mac in a non-work/corporate environment, not compared to a PC.  If we're comparing them to a PC then I agree with you - I wouldn't trade my Mac at work in for anything else, despite the occasional hiccups.

Comment: @Ryan Good point - I've added my thoughts and experiences to summarize stability of Mac at work vs Mac at home. Basically - you are right that some "work" software can cause issues. Most other changes add stability as opposed to introducing it.

Comment: All these links are by JAMF! Conflict of interest, much? Of course they push Macs in a corporate environment - that is how they sell their software. Not exactly objective!

Comment: @SamAndrew81 those are IBM’s results. I agree you should examine a company's funding model. They charge monthly, so if they don't deliver business value, their revenue fails. Also - are you saying IBM is predisposed to favor Mac so we should be sceptical of their data? Money is one thing that's purely objective, no?

Answer (score 0):

Ryan,

i've been admin in a couple work environments where they will boot more slowly.  in those cases the home mac and mac in work environment were really like different machines.

a few situations come to mind.

- the corporate mac authenticates your mac log in with an AD (windows server) network.  this can add a bit of time, but shouldn't be too much.  however there can be more complicated actions going on behind the scenes
- i've set up pretty complicated login hooks on work machines to change dns, update fonts, push in preferences, settings, and all this stuff to make the mac work easily for user at work.  this is run by a script as soon as someone logs in, but before they see their desktop.  these could definitely slow things down if it's elaborate.
- i've also set up the case where when a user logs in and sees their desktop and all their files--  these all actually live in a server.  this is no longer supported by latest macs, but it was handy to have all user files on one server for backing up, and scanning for viruses, etc.  however it did slow down the initial log in due to network speeds.

Comment: These macs are definitely on AD, so that's probably the culprit regarding login times (funnily enough when I get the password wrong it's quick to display an error message, but when I get it right it takes longer to log me in).  Beyond login issues though, I'm wondering if this generally explains system instability?  It's not crashing all of the time, but my work Macbook just behaves differently than my home computers in general: failing to wake up is the biggest issue I face, even after just closing the lid for a few minutes.

Comment: crash on wake is an an issue we battle sometimes.  it would be interesting to see what console shows logs saying during that failed wake.  but in short you're right:  they act like different machines due ot different configs, needs, security, hardware sometimes, all these things.  now i like to think the machines i set up at work are more stable/cleaner/better than people's home machines -- just through effort and attention.  they get a lot of attention since i don't like to hear complaints!

Comment: If you can escape binding - see about Apple's Enterprise Connect feature or a third party - open source tool like [NoMAD](https://gitlab.com/Mactroll/NoMAD) that get all the good out of binding without the lag or problems. We skip binding for performance, supportability and help desk labor resulting from binding.

Answer (score -1):

An indirect answer is to break down the issues on a broad level. It's hard to say without more detail, but as a SysAdmin I would generally say "yes." OS X has difficulty on a **Windows Domain**, which is what most corporate networks consist of. I'm actually dealing with a Mac issue on our Windows Domain right now. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, precisely.  Usually the explanation I've received from IT around the login delay issues are Active Directory integration hiccups (which oddly enough also occurred on my Windows machines at the same company).  The odd thing is why the network would have any effect on the behavior of the computer when running standard apps like Office (or maybe I just don't fully understand what happens when a computer is connected to a network and how different services and apps talk to each other).

Comment: Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).